# Problem with acronyms in figure caption using acro package

Tags: captions, acronyms, acro

I'm using the `acro` package for manage the acronyms. I have been used the `\ac{ }` command in the figure captions, however, in the `\appendix` figures, under the following configuration (see  MWE below), the acronym is not appearing in the long form even when it is called for the first time. How can I solve it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\DeclareAcronym{PVC}{
short=PVC,
long=Poli Vinil Chloride
}
\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\blindtext
\clearpage
\pagebreak
%
\appendix
\begin{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\section*{Supplementar Files}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{center}
\clearpage
\pagebreak
%%
\singlespacing
\section{Test}\label{sec:Esquemas-Filtros}
\acresetall
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
Dummy text
\caption{Some caption text to ilustrate the problem \ac{PVC}}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
%
\clearpage
\pagebreak
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is unrelated to appendices… `\caption` processes its argument twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit after @clemens's comment:**

If you change your `\ac{PVC}` to `\acf{PVC}` you have the same results as with my below code (for this specific example). But may be some day we will learn more from a new better answer...

**Old answer:**

You can redefine the declare acronym command to save a full name (I call it `\ACROfull{}` for every ACRO and use it instead of ac)

Before any declaration of acronym place this code:

```
\let\oldDeclareAcronym=\DeclareAcronym
\def\saveac#1{\xdef\temp{\acl{#1} (\acs{#1})}\global\expandafter\let\csname#1full\endcsname\temp}
\long\def\DeclareAcronym#1#2{\oldDeclareAcronym{#1}{#2}\saveac{#1}}
```

Then in your caption you can call `\PVCfull{}` instead of `\ac{PVC}` and it will print the same as `\ac{PVC}` out of the caption.

For some reason captions forbids the expansion of acronyms in their environment as far as I understood by trying.

Of course you could just write inside your caption: `\acl{#1} (\acs{#1})` instead of all the above declarations and redeclarations.

Comment: You know that `acro` already provides `\acf`?

Comment: And of course the *real* “problem” is that `\caption` processes its contents twice for measuring the width to be able to center short captions and to align longer captions…

Comment: @clemens I don't know... Just provided that solution after realized that the `\ac` command could not be expanded in the caption... Feel free to write a better answer and I will recommend to  the OP to select yours.

Comment: I probably won't have the time for the next few days :(

Comment: @clemens: It is a matter of seconds... Please... just copy paste OP's code and add an `f` on his `\ac`... I checked it and of course it works.

Comment: It isn't because there is a more general solution (I think) which requires more time

Comment: @clemens: Ok... I will just add this as an edit in my post and if some day you will find the time... I am curious to see and upvote your answer :P. Goodnight from Greece.

Comment: I posted an answer

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `article` typesets the caption differently depending on its length. If the caption is longer than one line it is typeset justified spanning the whole length otherwise it is centered. For this the caption is first put inside a box:

```
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
```

This means if the acronym is used for the first time inside a box (`\sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}`) and its width exceeds `\hsize` then when the caption is typeset (`#1: #2\par`) the acronym is not used for the first time any more! What's worse: the caption may not even be longer than `\hsize` any more! The following document demonstrates this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{PVC}{
  short = PVC,
  long = Poli Vinil Chloride
}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{Some caption text to illustrate the problem \ac{PVC}}
\end{figure}
\acresetall

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{\ac{PVC}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Provided you don't use any package which redefines `\@makecaption` and stick with the `article` class we can modify the definition of `\@makecaption` ourselves:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{PVC}{
  short = PVC,
  long = Poli Vinil Chloride
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makecaption[2]{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\acswitchoff#1: #2}% <<<<<
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil#1: #2\hfil}% <<<<<
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{Some caption text to illustrate the problem \ac{PVC}}
\end{figure}
\acresetall

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{\ac{PVC}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 For the analytic explanation and the solution. But to be honset I am not in place to understand everything. Have done similar things using minipages... But this is something more than my current knowledge.