# IEEEtran class, acronym package, first use in figure caption is actually second use

Tags: captions, ieeetran, acronyms

When using an acronym (`\ac{}` macro from the `acronym` package) for the first time in a multi-line figure caption in the `IEEEtran` class, it does not spell-out the full definition like it does in the body text or in single-line figure captions.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\newacro{FTP}{File Transfer Protocol}
\newacro{HTTP}{Hypertext Transfer Protocol}

I have some figures to show you.

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}Hello World!\end{minipage}
\caption{The \ac{FTP} Example with a Lot More Text to Word Wrap to the Next Line}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}Hello World!\end{minipage}
\caption{The \ac{HTTP} Example}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

...and resulting screenshot of the document:
[image: Screenshot of the typeset MWE]

From `ieeetran.cls`, this is the difference between the shorter and longer length captions, lines 2783-2788, dated 2015/08/26 version V1.8b:

```
% 3/2001 use footnotesize, not small; use two nonbreaking spaces, not one
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\normalfont\footnotesize {#1.}\nobreakspace\nobreakspace #2}%
\ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize%
% if caption is longer than a line, let it wrap around
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\normalfont\footnotesize {#1.}\nobreakspace\nobreakspace}%
\parbox[t]{\hsize}{\normalfont\footnotesize\noindent\unhbox\@tempboxa#2}%
```

Clearly, when the caption is too long for the line width, LaTeX tries again in a `parbox` but now the acronym has already been marked as used so in this second attempt, I only see the acronym's short definition.

Regarding the `IEEEtran` class, I tried other class options but can see in the .cls file that they all seem to use the same algorithm.

A couple similar answered questions are different enough that I have been unable to translate their solutions into a solution for this configuration.

- [One example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392829/263901) uses the `acro` package and the solution depends on its `\acswitchoff` macro.  The `acronym` package does not have a similar capability.
- [Another example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431633/263901) uses the `caption` package, which the `IEEEtran` class does not load.

How can I overcome this `IEEEtran` "first try" that marks acronyms as used so that my multi-line figure captions can have acronyms' full definitions for their first use?

Answer (score 0):

There is a work-around for this question but I believe there is a better fix for the `IEEEtran` class.

The work-around involves putting this code into your document preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makecaption}[2]{%
% test if is a for a figure or table
\ifx\@captype\@IEEEtablestring%
% if a table, do table caption
\footnotesize\bgroup\par\centering\@IEEEtabletopskipstrut{\normalfont\footnotesize #1}\\{\normalfont\footnotesize\scshape #2}\par\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}\egroup%
\@IEEEtablecaptionsepspace
% if not a table, format it as a figure
\else
\@IEEEfigurecaptionsepspace
% 3/2001 use footnotesize, not small; use two nonbreaking spaces, not one
\def\tempcapdesc{#1.\nobreakspace\nobreakspace #2}%
\let\oldacused\acused%
\let\oldAC@placelabel\AC@placelabel%
\let\acused\@gobble%
\let\AC@placelabel\@gobble%
%\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\normalfont\footnotesize {#1.}\nobreakspace\nobreakspace #2}%
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\normalfont\footnotesize\tempcapdesc}%
\let\acused\oldacused
\let\AC@placelabel\oldAC@placelabel
\ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize%
% if caption is longer than a line, let it wrap around
%\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\normalfont\footnotesize {#1.}\nobreakspace\nobreakspace}%
%\parbox[t]{\hsize}{\normalfont\footnotesize\noindent\unhbox\@tempboxa#2}%
\parbox[t]{\hsize}{\normalfont\footnotesize\noindent\tempcapdesc}%
% if caption is shorter than a line, center if conference, left justify otherwise
\else%
%\ifCLASSOPTIONconference \hbox to\hsize{\normalfont\footnotesize\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
%\else \hbox to\hsize{\normalfont\footnotesize\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
\ifCLASSOPTIONconference \hbox to\hsize{\normalfont\footnotesize\hfil\tempcapdesc\hfil}%
\else \hbox to\hsize{\normalfont\footnotesize\tempcapdesc\hfil}%
\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

Basically, this is a modified version of lines 2774-2793 of `ieeetran.cls` (dated 2015/08/26 version V1.8b, which is the latest as of this post) (a defining of the `\@makecaption` macro) enclosed between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.  Here is how it works:

1. To overcome the logic that expanded the caption to measure its width and then expand it again if its width is greater than the horizontal space available, I created the `\tempcapdesc` macro to streamline access to the `\@makecaption` arguments.
2. I followed [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431633) to temporarily gobble the applicable `acronym` package macros, `\acused` and `\AC@placelabel`.
3. While those macros were being "gobbled," I ran the original width test, `\ifdim`.
4. With the width test done, I restored the `acronym` package macros.
5. Regardless of the result of the width test, I re-expanded the caption according to the existing IEEE style but this time, the `acronym` package macros `\acused` and `\AC@placelabel` work as if I am expanding the enclosed `\ac` macros for the first time.

NOTES:

- I kept the original code in line but commented it out for reference and comparison.
- This work-around applies to documents that do not use the `compsoc` option of the `ieeetran` class.  If you need this work-around for a `compsoc` document, then you will need to adapt this solution to the code immediately preceding this modified excerpt from `ieeetran.cls`.

---

I looked for a better fix that could serve as a patch to the `IEEEtran` class and thought of a couple options.

First though, note that `ieeetran.cls` has a non-trivial nesting of conditions (if-else statements) to format captions differently according to the `IEEEtran` package options and whether they are table or figure captions.  This code spans lines 2730-2794.  Looking at this code and comparing the styles did not reveal any straightforward way of simplifying it.

One option is to adapt this work-around into the `IEEEtran` class.  Although it is an option, I do not believe it to be a good option.  Primarily, there are likely a lot of `IEEEtran` users that do not also use the `acronym` package so the `\let` statements to temporarily disable/gobble the `acronym` package macros would cause LaTeX to throw an error that it cannot find the specified macro.  Although overcoming this would be easy enough with the `\@ifpackageloaded` macro, this quickly becomes unwieldy with having to implement it within each of the if statement branches.  Furthermore, `acronym` is just one of at least three packages that provide acronym capabilities (`acro` and `glossaries` being two others) and we would need to account for those packages as well.  This option would approximately double the number of lines of code currently spanning lines 2730-2794.

Another option is to create a macro outside of the current captions conditions nesting that performs the width test.  The challenge here is having the width test account for the style because style can affect the width.  Having this width test macro separate makes it easier for users to renew/redefine just this macro to account for whatever acronym-capable package they are using.  These re-definitions could also be made available in the `IEEEtran` class documentation, like the examples available here:  https://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/.

There may still be a better way to improve the `IEEEtran` class to account for acronym usage in figure captions.  If posted here, the votes will help decide.